# Finding/Calculating the bend "direction" of a Sheet metal CAD model

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

In a computer program I am working on, there is this property that I call the bend "direction" that I would like to assign to bend features of a CAD model based on the side in which the acute/obtuse angle of the bend is located. For example, in the diagrams below I use +/- for the assignment.
[image]

Above is the model in question and below is the bend direction assigned to each bend. (+) for the bends whose acute/obtuse angle side is facing same side and (-) otherwise.

[image]

Is there a mathematical method that I can use to determine and assign bend "directions". If you know Opencascade C++ library you can also assist with a function(s) I can use you can to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just assign clockwise bend being positive , and anticlockwise negative.There's nothing special mathematical in it , except the fact that mostly adopted positive rotating direction in math is anticlockwise, i.e. opposite to your choice.